# get elements loaded via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm loading some stuff from a php page using AJAX. this works fine.

but now I need to get the elements (button or form or div) loaded using AJAX.

My current code that doesn't work is this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {


$(function(){   
    $('.delForm').on('submit', function(dleItem){


        // prevent native form submission here
        dleItem.preventDefault();

        // now do whatever you want here


        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'),// <-- get method of form
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            //url: "cart.php",
            data: $(this).serialize(), // <-- serialize all fields into a string that is ready to be posted to your PHP file
            beforeSend: function(){

            },
            success: function(data){

            }
        });
    });


    });
  });
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
document($('.delForm')).on('submit', function(dleItem){
```

and this:

```
body($('.delForm')).on('submit', function(dleItem){
```

but this will stop my code working.

could someone please advise on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are not `document()` or `body()` methods unless you wrote one or included some library. You also have a ready method wrapped in a ready method. Makes no sense. `jQuery(document).ready(function(){})` is the same thing as `$(function(){})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$(document).on('submit', '.delForm', function(dleItem) {});
```

Comment: My Bad, I had a typo in there. it works fine now. thanks ever so much.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept the answer if it suited your requirements.

Comment: sure, it says I need to wait for 2 minutes. i will accept it as soon as the 2 minutes is up.